# Is $f$ an absolutely continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2^{n}\pi x)}{n\cdot2^{n}}, \,\,\,\,\,\, x\in [-1, 1].$$

Is $f$ an absolutely continuous function?

If yes how can I show it?

If not how about the total variation of $f$ ?

Comment: Please define absolutely continuous.

Comment: Here I mean [absolute continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity)